# R cannot be resolved to a variable (different scenario)

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Firstly, I have searched and seen similar questions on Stackoverflow however I'm building outside Android studio or Eclipse so mine is a bit different and I'm looking for a solution or alternative if possible.
I am building a plugin that sends messages between Java and Javascript using Cordova.

I have 3 lines to resolve:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

mPreview = (CameraSourcePreview) findViewById(R.id.preview);
mGraphicOverlay = (GraphicOverlay) findViewById(R.id.faceOverlay);
```

Specifically just the `setContentView(R.layout.main)`, `findViewById(R.id.preview)` and `findViewById(R.id.faceOverlay)`. The layout file is in `../../../res/layout/main.xml` and `../../../res/layout-land/main.xml`.

All I want is a way to access, I do not have a `R.java` file and I'm not very experienced with Java unlike Javascript.

Is there a way to point to those files please, thanks.

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

  <com.cordovaplugincamerapreview
      android:id="@+id/preview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.cordovaplugincamerapreview
        android:id="@+id/faceOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  </com.cordovaplugincamerapreview>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think it does not matter if you don't have android studio or eclipse. You need to do a gradle build so that R.java file gets generated. And then import it in your Java class.

Comment: Just found what may be the answer, will test tomorrow: https://github.com/donaldp24/CanvasCameraPlugin/commit/e9f0b1959bacd8b0370d2593e7967bbb6efaf6a3

Comment: What is the purpose of layout-land directory ? There might be a conflict of these two files.

Comment: May be for landscape mode for Mobile